# ES File Folder Remote Manager is disconnect by auto?

Tags: ftp

I am using ES File Folder for exchanging the file from Mobile to PC. 
The issue is , the Remote Manager is automatically disconnected in times.
I want to manual set to Start (the connection) and to Stop the connection. Is there is any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there an issue in using MTP via USB cable for file exchange? It is plain and simple.

Comment: No, not using USB. The mobile is connected thru Wifi